# Debugging IO saturation on linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ext4, io

I have the following problem. On one machine, device IO is saturated to 100% util (via iostat -x 1) during one program execution. While on other less powerful CPU/GPU wise there's no such problem, that is iostat converges to around 0 quickly.

CPU is not saturated, that is process isn't CPU intensive. 
GPU is saturated on other machine, while on IO util 100% GPU isn't saturated.

RAM is not saturated on neither machine.

For this program GPU should be the bottleneck, not IO.

The program is run with docker, specifically nvidia-docker on both machines, with same docker image.

On problematic machine I've run hdparm -tT and there isn't much difference between machines. File system is ext4, 1.4TB/1.8TB occupied. Data is composed of 1-3MB files totaling to 400GB.

The process is multithreaded/multiprocess where each subprocess communicates to main process what data has it read and processed (since python GIL).

I'm running out of ideas what could be the problem and how to debug it.

EDIT:

docker version 1.13.1 on problematic machine, 1.13.0 on ok machine. 
kernel Linux 4.4.0-57 on ok machine, 4.4.0-62 on problematic machine

Comment: The problem is very likely I/O throughput: Different types of harddisks that take a different time to complete head seeks/random access writes, have a different amount of internal buffer etc, have a SATA connection with different speed (check `dmesg`), etc.